# Limit default number of search results in Content Navigator (e.g. 50 hits)

Tags: plugins, ibm-content-navigator

I want to limit the default number of search results in Content Navigator. Do I need to develop a plugin here. If yes, which methods to overwrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of results from Repository.

1. Open repository
2. Click connect
3. Navigate to Search tab and you will 
   find an option "Number of results"